# Serializing reverse relationship of a ForeignKey with a DRF ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to generate a data structure following this sample:

```
[
  {
    "name": "groupname",
    "key": "grouping1",
    "base_templates": [
      {
        "identity": "123456",
        "name": "createxxx"
      },
      {
        "identity": "112233",
        "name": "deletexxx"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "groupname2",
    "key": "grouping2",
    "base_templates": [
      {
        "identity": "123999999",
        "name": "runxxxx"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

These are the models I'm using：

```
class TicketCategory(Model.models):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="name", max_length=100, unique=True)
    key = models.CharField(verbose_name="key", max_length=100, unique=True)


class BaseTemplate(Model.models):
    identity = models.UUIDField(verbose_name="tag", default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        TicketCategory, verbose_name="grouping", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="name", max_length=100, default="", db_index=True
    )
```

The serializers and the view I am trying to use:

```
class BaseTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BaseTemplate
        fields = "__all__"


class TicketCategoryDashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    basetmplate = BaseTemplateSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TicketCategory
        fields = "__all__"


class TicketCategoryDashboard(APIView):

    def get(self, request: Request):
        r = TicketCategory.objects.all().last()
        serializer = TicketCategoryDashboardSerializer(r)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

How can I generate the serialized data in that sample structure I have provided? I'm having trouble to generate that structure with the reverse side of the model relationship.

Comment: Please, consider editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a [`related_name="base_templates"`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to your `category = models.ForeignKey(...)`, and then you can define your serializer as:

```
class TicketCategoryDashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    base_templates = BaseTemplateSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TicketCategory
        fields = "__all__"
```

[The Django documentation has examples on it as well.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: How should I write the code of the reverse query model? I'm a rookie:)

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by "code of the reverse query model". I assumed you were simply trying to serialize the reverse relation and that's what my answer was about. By adding the `reverse_name="base_templates"` you should be able to access the reverse side with something like this: `ticket_category = TicketCategory.objects.all().last()` and `ticket_category.base_templates.all()` would return all `BaseTemplate`s for that `ticket_category`.